# Перекласти "очаг болезни", але не "вогнище хвороби"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Знайшла проблему в перекладі сталого медичного виразу рос.мовою "очаг болезни", "очаг инфекции", гугл перекладач не дуже тішить, подаючи мені "вогнище".

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/voghnyshhe) містить значення, схоже на те, що треба

> 3. перен. Джерело, місце, звідки що-небудь поширюється; центр, зосередження чого-небудь.

Але приклади не задовольняють, бо там нема прикладів з медицини. Як на мене, тут відчувається вплив рос. медичної термінології та форма переносу слова шляхом прямого перекладу. Чи є варіанти передати зміст вислову іншим словосполученням?

P. S.: Мається на увазі ділянка тіла, а не географічна локація.

Comment: «Очаг болезни/инфекции» — мається на увазі ділянка тіла людини (звідки хвороба/інфекція поширюється на інші органи) чи географічна територія (звідки йде епідемія)?

Comment: @Sasha питання виникло щодо значення ділянки тіла

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **(в)огнище**:

  [«Російсько-український словник» Кримського і Єфремова (1924–1933)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B3&scope=rusb&dicts=1):

  > Оча́г — о́гнище, бага́ття, (гал.) ва́тра.
  >
  > - <…>
  > - Оча́г заразы, болезней — о́гнище по́шести, хоро́б.

  [ABBYY Lingvo Russian-Ukrainian Dictionary (ймовірно, на основі російсько-українського словника В. Бусела видавництва «Перун»)](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B3):

  > очаг:
  >
  > 1. вогнище, огнище
  > 2. (средоточие, источник распространения чего-л.) вогнище, огнище, осередок, -дку, осереддя

  Чому цей варіант не росіянізм, [пояснює follower у своїй відповіді](/a/5002).
- **осередок** (**осереддя**):

  Особисто я підтримую [відповідь Paul Gor](/a/5001), причому не лише в контексті території, а й у контексті ділянки тіла (нижче приклади для обох контекстів).

  [ABBYY Lingvo Russian-Ukrainian Dictionary (ймовірно, на основі російсько-українського словника В. Бусела видавництва «Перун»)](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B3): див. цитату вище.

  [Підручник для ВМНЗ IV р. а. «Епідеміологія» за ред. І. П. Колеснікової](https://books.google.com/books?id=-YfVCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22):

  > Осередок інфекційної хвороби — місце перебування джерела збудника інфекції разом з оточуючою територією, в межах якої при даному механізмі передачі може розповсюджуватись збудник серед людей.

  [Зі статті «топічний» у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/topichnyj):

  > Особливий інтерес становить результат психологічного експерименту для так званого топічного діагнозу, який допомагає визначити, де саме в головному мозку локалізується осередок хвороби (Наука і життя, 6, 1968, 35).

  [В. М. Бобирьов, Т. А. Петрова та ін., навчальний посібник для ВМНЗ IV р. а. «Фармакотерапія в стоматології»](https://books.google.com/books?id=tpnSCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97%22):

  > …препарат не може проникати в органи чи тканини, де знаходиться осередок інфекції…

  [Д. Ю. Кривченя, С. В. Лисак, навчальний посібник для ВМНЗ IV р. а. «Хірургічні захворювання у дітей»](https://books.google.com/books?id=ve0KCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97%22):

  > Під «малими хірургічними методами» розуміють активні впливи на осередок інфекції (дренування, пункція, ендоскопічні маніпуляції).

  [«Медична мікробіологія, вірусологія та імунологія» за ред. В. П. Широбокова](https://books.google.com/books?id=niPrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA472&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97%22):

  > У 50х роках ХХ століття описаний осередок інфекції у Донецькій області, нині випадків хвороби там не зареєстровано.

  [Закон України «Про захист населення від інфекційних хвороб»](http://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/1645-14):

  > осередок інфекційної хвороби — місце (об'єкт, територія), де виявлено джерело інфекції та відповідні фактори передачі інфекції

  [А. В. Чорновіл, Р. Ю. Грицько, «Клінічне медсестринство в інфектології з елементами епідеміології»](http://skaz.com.ua/biolog/19194/index.html?page=3):

  > ЕПІДЕМІОЛОГІЧНЕ ОБСТЕЖЕННЯ ОСЕРЕДКУ ІНФЕКЦІЙНОЇ ХВОРОБИ
  >
  > Епідемічний осередок — це місце перебування джерела збудника інфекції з навколишньою територією у тих межах, в яких заразний чинник може передатися.

  Ну й ще докупи [стаття для «купировать» з «Російсько-українського народного сучасного словника» (2009–…) на R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&dicts=10), хоч це не дуже надійне джерело:

  > купировать очаг воспаления — локалізувати осередок (вогнище) запалення
- **джерело** — не впевнений, що це слово підходить (можливо, значення трішки інше), приклади наводити не буду.

Answer (score 9):

Якщо мова йде про певну територію, то ще є слово [ОСЕРЕ́ДОК](http://sum.in.ua/s/oseredok)

> /  Місце зародження, виникнення, джерело поширення чого-небудь.

Answer (score 6):

Чи можна тоді…

- польське [*ognisko*](http://wsjp.pl/index.php?id_hasla=9898&id_znaczenia=5022941&l=19&ind=0):

  > 4. chorobowe
  >
  >    miejsce w organizmie człowieka, w którym nastąpiły zmiany chorobowe
- словацьке [*ohnisko*](http://slovniky.juls.savba.sk/?w=ohnisko&c=dde1&d=psken&d=priezviska&d=ma&d=bernolak&d=hssjV&d=noundb&d=sssj&d=obce&d=locutio&d=sss&d=un&d=kssj4&d=peciar&d=pskcs&d=psp&d=scs), *plemenisko*:

  > ohnisko ²
  >
  > 3. stred, z kt. sa niečo šíri, centrum: *o. zemetrasenia, vojny, o. odporu*;
  >
  > ---
  >
  > *plemenisko chorôb*
- як і чеське [*ohnisko*](https://nechybujte.cz/slovnik-soucasne-cestiny/ohnisko?)

  > ohnisko
  >
  > 3. středisko, z kterého se něco šíří

… теж вважати змосвокщеними?

Comment: Не знаю, але стало цікаво